# IE8/9 window.postMessage not working, but why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

The "postMessage" is an HTML5 API, it is available in all major browsers including IE8/9. What I am trying to do is to create a popup window from a page, and be able to talk to the popup window using "postMessage". This works in every browser except IE8/9. Disappointed!

It looks like IE8/9 only allows the communication between iframes, but not between two windows, even the windows are within the same hierarchy.

Comment: Could you please share your code with us here?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. [IE 8+ does not support `postMessage` across tabs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging), only frames and iframes. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.postMessage` method *works*, you just need to understand *how* it works from IE8 and up. Unfortunately, for IE8 and IE9 it will not do what you're seeking (though it does in IE10). While you can send messages between frames in IE8/9, you cannot send messages to a separate window.

There is a work-around that works in *some* instances. Martin Beeby discusses it in the last paragraph of his blog post on the issue: [PostMessage Popups and IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/12/21/postmessage-popups-and-ie.aspx).

For more on this, and a few other caveats, see Eric Lawrence's [post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx).

Comment: As Lawrence notes in an update to his post, this is _still_ not fixed as of IE11.

Answer (score 44):

I found that `.postMessage()` in IE9 was unreliable unless I used `String`s.

My workaround was to simply call `.postMessage(JSON.stringify({object: 'data'}))` and use `JSON.parse()` in the `onMessage()` function on the other end.

Comment: This solved my issue perfectly in IE8 and IE9. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the `data` property is readonly in the `MessageEvent` object so I had to  append the parsed object from the string as another property to access it afterwards. Don't know if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: This issue has been driving me up the wall as well! Thank you so much for this nice little tidbit.

Comment: Fixes the problem in IE 11, too, and is still necessary.