# "Message" event listener in IE9 can't receive object as event.data value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-9

I've got an event listener of this kind:

```
function onGetMsg(event) {
    alert(event.data.message);
}
window.addEventListener('message', onGetMsg);
```

The **event.data** structure is:

```
{ 
  message: ‘some msg’, 
  data: [ {...}, ... ] 
}
```

In other browsers (and in IE10+) it works in predictably way. But IE9 sees **event.data** as a string `"[object Object]"`, so **onGetMsg** fails to get "message" property.

Is this a common problem for IE9 or maybe my mistake? And how can it possibly be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own question was not quite correct, as I find it out now.
I forgot to mention the fact of how the messages are sent:

```
window.postMessage(obj, url);
```

And this is the key to my problem. So the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830480/ie8-9-window-postmessage-not-working-but-why) is also suitable for my case.